# Eliminate VMware Popups/Notifications that Span Multiple Monitors on Windows 10

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, vmware, popups

So long story short, I have VMware Workstation 15 installed, running on a multiple monitor system using Windows 10.  Although I am only using a virtual machine on one monitor, as well as only running the entire program on one monitor, when any and all popups or notifications come onto screen, they span many monitors and it's quite annoying.

Please see attached image as an example.

Does anyone know a way to fix this and have the popup notifications appear only on one screen?  I'm exhausted of all the searches I've done which solely address having a GuestOS span multiple monitors.

[[image: Example Popup[1]]

Comment: I am also running into this issue @hawkhorrow. Did you ever find a solution for it?
I have tried uninstall/reinstall and updating to the latest version to no avail